# how to fit a concatenated model when we have two X_train and two y_train

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, concatenation, training-data

I want to concatenate two CNN models, each one with different input.
the first model has its x_train and y_train
the second one too X_train, Y_train
(it's the same image but in the second branch I did some processing)

```
`merge = Concatenate()([model_a.output, model_b.output])
 merged_out = Dense(units=512, activation='relu')(merge)
 merged_out = Dense(units=1, activation='softmax')(merged_out)
 from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
 merged_model = Model([model_a.input, model_b.input], merged_out)
 merged_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

​

Now the problem is how to fit the merged model

​

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Where do things break?

Your `merged_model` is a model, you can just call `fit` on it, it expects a pair of images, just like the way you defined it: [image_a, image_b]. So you need to create a dataset ([image_a, image_b], labels) to train it on.

So your data pipeline would need to be something like this:

```
ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(...)

def preprocess_ab(images, labels):
  image_a = preprocess_a(images)
  image_b = preprocess_b(images)

  return (image_a, image_b), labels

ds =  ds.map(preprocess_ab)

model.fit(ds)
```

Comment: can you please guide me on how to do this?

Comment: I've added a code example.